# Can we modify a document class properties with CE APIs and how to do it?

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine, filenet

I'm trying to update security for document class using automation. Here I need to add/modify users who can access the class instead of doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the URL below, this is for updating the document object security, but you can apply the same for the document class definition

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.5.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/sec_procedures.htm#sec_procedures__sec_procedures_setting_permissions

Comment: The link is not working. I got it with DocumentClassDefinition. Thanks for the answer